# UIPopover repopulate content with another NIB

Tags: iphone, ios4, uipopovercontroller, uipopover

I have a UIPopover that pops up when a user pushes a button, pulling up a form for the user to fill out.

I want to repopulate this popover (and resize it to the size to a new CGSize) when the user clicks the "complete" button, taking them to a confirmation page, before closing the window.  I've looked for the documentation for both the UIPopoverController class and the UIPopoverController Protocol and haven't had any luck.

Can anyone provide some sample code about how I'd go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIPopoverController has its contentViewController property which you can set to change the view controller being shown on the popover, here is a reference [UIPopover ref](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html), look for setContentViewController:animated:

You can use that property to do what you need...theres also other ways to acomplish your task, such as using navigation controllers, etc